# Viewing column indices and names at once

Tags: python, pandas

I need to slice several different datasets that contain a lot of extraneous columns. It's easier for me to glance over the indices of the columns I want, and tell Python to save these columns, than type out their names one by one. For instance if I want to save only SCHOOL_DATE, STUDENT_DATE, STUDENT_P2_DATE, I'd rather tell Python to save column[3, 5:6] or something.

However, I can't find a quick way to view column names right next to their index.

Currently I just run a debugger up to a line where I create an array of my column names, then I view as array in Pycharm to quickly identify which # belongs to which name. I also tried iterating through columns to return their index position and name, but maybe because I don't know well how Python objects behave, wasn't able to get that to work.

```py
SQLdf = pd.read_csv(desktoppath + SchoolFromSQLfilename)
cols = np.array(SQLdf.columns)
print(SQLdf.columns)
```

I put a debugger break on the print line. Obviously, I'd like to just print out the matches though straight into the console, than having to take a few point and click steps to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do with `enumerate`

```
list(enumerate(df.columns))
[(0, 'id'), (1, 'A')]
```

Then pass to `np.r_[3,[3:4],[5:8]]`